# Button Style in Resource not Applied to Buttons

Tags: wpf

Can someone please explain to me why this doesn't work? The Buttons in the ToolBar are not getting the Black BorderBrush property setting. I've tried TargetType="Button" and TargetType="{x:Type Button}" but neither work. I've done almost exactly the same thing for a series of Labels and it worked fine. I'm pretty new to WPF. Is there something I'm not understanding about style precedence here? Thanks!

```
...Window Definition...

<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ToolBar Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0">
        <Button>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="Auto">
                <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16" Fill="LightBlue" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Rectangle>
                <Label Padding="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">Redraw</Label>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
        ... More Buttons ...
    </ToolBar>
</Grid>

... End Window Definition ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}"
       TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
            Value="Black" />
</Style>
```

from [How to: Style Controls on a ToolBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613577(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The ToolBar defines **ResourceKey** objects to specify the **style of controls** *within the ToolBar*. To style a control in a ToolBar, set the **x:key** attribute of the style to a ResourceKey defined in ToolBar.

The ToolBar defines the following ResourceKey objects:

- ButtonStyleKey
- CheckBoxStyleKey
- ComboBoxStyleKey
- MenuStyleKey
- RadioButtonStyleKey
- SeparatorStyleKey
- TextBoxStyleKey
- ToggleButtonStyleKey

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Guess I should read those docs some more :) Thanks for answering!